# Matlab: Manipulation of Matrix and Storing them

Tags: matlab, matrix

How do I assign all the values of position in to a new variable?

```
A = [ -1   0  -2   0   0
       2   8   0   1   0
       0   0   3   0  -2
       0  -3   2   0   0
       1   2   0   0  -4];

  a=size(A);
  b=size(A);
  c=0;
  position=0;
  for i=1:a 
      for j=1:b 
          if A(i,j) ~=0
              c=c+1;
              position=position+1;
              S(c,:)=[position,i,j,A(i,j)];
          end
      end
  end
```

Result:
S =

```
 1     1     1    -1
 2     1     3    -2
 3     2     1     2
 4     2     2     8
 5     2     4     1
 6     3     3     3
 7     3     5    -2
 8     4     2    -3
 9     4     3     2
10     5     1     1
11     5     2     2
12     5     5    -4
```

Something like 
position=
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

And the same thing for i

Comment: You want to extract the first column of `S`? Just do `position = S(:,1)'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you would save yourself a lot of grief with the [`find` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
A = [ -1   0  -2   0   0
       2   8   0   1   0
       0   0   3   0  -2
       0  -3   2   0   0
       1   2   0   0  -4];

[I,J,V] = find(A);
```

Will put the `(i,j)` locations of the non-zero elements of in `I` and `J` respectively, with the values in `V`.  If you really want the `position` vector you can just create it with `position = 1:length(V);`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you ill always have `c=position`, so one must be redundant. At the end of the loop, you can pull out the values of `position` by doing `S(:,1)` which gives the first column of `S`. Likewise you can get the values of `i` by doing `S(:,2)`. Is that what you are looking for?